# How to cherry-pick through GitHub's API

Tags: git, github, github-api

I'm having trouble performing a *simple* cherry-pick through the GitHub API. It must be possible, but it's not clear to me how...

I'm developing a chatbot for Slack in C# to help manage Kubernetes environments and GitHub releases, and want to extend it with a **hotfix feature**. Given an environment, it should create a branch that matches that current release and cherry-pick one or more commit SHA's in there, as supplied by the author of the request through Slack.

All the plumbing is in place. Using the `POST /repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs` I am able to create the branch that matches the specific release. This means I have both a `branch name`, `commit SHA` and `tree SHA` ready for the next step; cherry-picking one or more commit SHA's into this branch. Using `POST /repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits` I am able to create a commit, but I'm not sure which tree and/or parent to use - which probably causes the issues I encounter calling `POST /repos/:owner/:repo/merges` , as it returns me status 409 (merge conflict) where locally, of course, it does not.

The only real example I seem to find is https://github.com/tibdex/github-cherry-pick. However, it does not really match my scenario, and I have a hard time understanding the Git inner workings.

My scenario (latest to oldest);

```
* commit E (current state of `master`)
* commit D
* commit C (deployed to environment)
* commit B
* commit A
```

In this scenario, I would like to cherry-pick commit E into a new branch off of commit C, creating a set (A, B, C, E) that I can release.

```
* commit E (current state of `master`)
* commit D
|
| * commit E (new branch, to be deployed)
|/
* commit C (deployed to environment)
* commit B
* commit A
```

Basically what I need is a GitHub API version of this bash;

```
git checkout -b {new-branch-name} {sha}
git cherry-pick {sha}
git push main {new-branch-name}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Cherry-picking is a form of merge, and merges can result in conflicts. Conflicts require resolution through your index and work-tree, and GitHub repositories don't have a work-tree. There may or may not be a way to handle cherry-picks that don't have conflicts, since GitHub *do* perform behind-the-scenes non-conflicting merges when doing pull requests. They automatically detect conflicts and make the pull-request un-mergeable for these cases. But, whether or not your goal is possible (via GitHub APIs), I don't know how to do it there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I implemented cherry-pick over the Github API, in pseudo-code:

```
// here is a commit, for example, from a pull request:
listOfCommits = GET /repos/$owner/$repo/pulls/$number/commits
commit = listOfCommits.head // the first one in the list

// Here is the branch we want to cherry-pick to:
branch = GET /repos/$owner/$repo/branches/$branchName
branchSha = branch.commit.sha
branchTree = branch.commit.commit.tree.sha

// Create a temporary commit on the branch, which extends as a sibling of
// the commit we want but contains the current tree of the target branch:
parentSha = commit.parents.head // first parent -- there should only be one
tempCommit = POST /repos/$owner/$repo/git/commits { "message": "temp",
                                                    "tree": branchTree,
                                                    "parents": [parentSha] }

// Now temporarily force the branch over to that commit
PATCH /repos/$owner/$repo/git/refs/heads/$refName { sha = tempCommit.sha,
                                                    force = true }

// Merge the commit we want into this mess:
merge = POST /repos/$owner/$repo/merges { "base": branchName
                                  "head": commit.sha }

// and get that tree!
mergeTree = merge.commit.tree.sha

// Now that we know what the tree should be, create the cherry-pick commit.
// Note that branchSha is the original from up at the top.
cherry = POST /repos/$owner/$repo/git/commits { "message": "looks good!",
                                                "tree": mergeTree,
                                                "parents": [branchSha] }

// Replace the temp commit with the real commit:
PATCH /repos/$owner/$repo/git/refs/heads/$refName { sha = cherry.sha,
                                                    force = true }

// Done!
```

Git experts, please advise, but I believe this accomplishes:

```
git checkout -b {new-branch-name} {sha}
git cherry-pick {sha}
git push main {new-branch-name}
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer works, but it isn't clear why.

The following is taken from a comment in my gist of this script (in golang): https://gist.github.com/sashamor/7918b3be758759440feb7825547370f9

GitHub doesn't support creating cherry-pick commits directly with it's API.
However, it does support creating commit objects in the git tree. So, we'll
create a new cherry-pick commit from first principles.

To create a commit, we need 3 things:

1. The commit message.
2. The parent commit.
3. The tree (aka, the state of all objects in the repo at this commit).

For a cherry-pick commit, that's mostly easy:

1. The message is easy - we use the message from the original commit, plus a
   "cherry-picked from ..." footer.
2. The parent SHA is also easy - we use the SHA of the commit we'd like to
   cherry-pick onto, extending the tree.
3. The tree is the tricky part - we'll need to create a new git object that
   contains the files in the state we'd like them to be in, then use that.

The steps below are for creating the tree SHA. Once we have that, we can
create the commit.

To get the tree, we can use the merge API. Currently, the GitHub merge API
requires two things:

1. The branch to merge onto.
2. The SHA of the commit we'd like to merge.

At first glance, a solution seems to be to use merge with:

1. The branch to cherry-pick onto.
2. The commit to cherry-pick.

However, this has the caveat that all commits *before* the cherry-pick
commit, that aren't in the branch to cherry-pick onto, are included in the
merge. We don't want this. To fix this, we can "trick" git into only
including the cherry-pick commit, by (temporarily) setting the parent of the
branch to the parent of the commit we'd like to cherry-pick. That way, when
git performs the merge, it detects that the parent of the branch commit we're
merging onto matches the parent of the commit we're merging with, and merges
a tree of size 1, containing only the cherry-pick commit.

To create this new "tip of tree" commit:

1. The message doesn't matter - it's lost.
2. The parent is the parent of the commit we'd like to cherry-pick - this
   way, both the cherry-pick commit and the branch have the same parent.
3. The tree is the tree of the branch we'd like to cherry-pick onto.

We then create a temporary branch that points to this commit, so we can merge
onto it. We can then call merge with:

1. A branch with a tree matching the branch we're cherry-picking onto, and a
   parent matching the parent of the commit we're cherry-picking.
2. The commit to cherry-pick.
   The resulting commit of this merge operation has the tree SHA we need.

Finally, we can use this to create the cherry-pick commit. This can be
repeated as many times as needed, with the new cherry-pick commit being the
base branch each time.

Comment: I don't get why creating a temporary branch each commit tho.
Couldn't we just update the single temporary branch to the latest 'baseCommitForMerging'?