# Octokit.net - Cherry-pick merge commit

Tags: .net, git, cherry-pick, github-app, octokit.net

I've created a .NET equivalent of Probot where I hooked up the `SmeeClient` during development. I'm trying to build a Github bot which cherry-picks merge commits into release branches, depending on the labels on the pull-request.

My code for the `MyWebhookProcessor` essentially looks like this:

```
public class GithubProcessor : BaseWebhookProcessor
{
    private readonly IAuthenticatedGithubService authenticatedGithubService;
    public GithubProcessor(IAuthenticatedGithubService authenticatedGithubService, ISignatureService signatureService, IOptions<BotOptions> botOptions)
        : base(signatureService, botOptions)
    {
        this.authenticatedGithubService = authenticatedGithubService;
    }

    protected override async Task ProcessPullRequestWebhookAsync(WebhookHeaders headers, PullRequestEvent pullRequestEvent, PullRequestAction action)
    {
        if (pullRequestEvent is PullRequestClosedEvent ev)
        {
            var client = await authenticatedGithubService.GetAuthenticatedGithubClient(ev.Installation!.Id);
            var mergeCommit = await client.Git.Commit.Get(ev.Repository!.Id, ev.PullRequest.MergeCommitSha);

            //await client.Git.Reference.Update(0, "master", new Octokit.ReferenceUpdate())
            foreach (var label in ev.PullRequest.Labels)
            {
                var releaseBranch = await client.Repository.Branch.Get(ev.Repository!.Id, label.Name);
                if (releaseBranch != null)
                {
                    // Here we should be able to cherry-pick the mergeCommit into the releaseBranch
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the [OctoKit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) doesn't seem to contain any method to cherry-pick commits. I could however create a new commit, but I haven't found how to copy changes from the mergeCommit to a new one. The project is hosted [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.GithubApps/blob/master/MintPlayer.GithubApps/GithubProcessor.cs#L34).

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: [Interesting link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53859199/how-to-cherry-pick-through-githubs-api)

Comment: Just adding [this link](https://github.com/googleapis/repo-automation-bots/blob/main/packages/cherry-pick-bot/src/cherry-pick.ts#L137) as a ref