# How to cherry-pick a commit from another repository using GitHub API

Tags: git, github, github-api

I'm playing a bit with GitHub API, so:
I've created two repositories:

- repo1
- repo2

And I wanted to know if there is a way to cherry-pick a commit from a certain branch in repo1 to a certain branch in repo2 using GitHub API.

I've achieved this with git cli using this guide:
[cherry-pick between repos](https://dev.to/jmalvarez/how-to-cherry-pick-a-commit-from-another-repository-4pf1)

And now I need to do the same using GitHub API.
I would appreciate if someone could give me a hand here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53859199/how-to-cherry-pick-through-githubs-api, you need to do everything manually (merging the tree, creating the commit) – not sure if it is possible to do that cross-repository (I would be surprised if it is possible)

Answer (score 0):

- Here is a sample file which you can use.
- Don't forget to set all the variables

```py
import requests
import json

# GitHub credentials
username = 'username' 
token = 'token'

# Repositories and commit details
source_repo = 'source_repo'
target_repo = 'target_repo'
commit_sha = 'commit_sha'
branch = 'branch'

# Headers for the API request
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
    'Authorization': f'token {token}',
}

# Get the commit from the source repository
commit_url = f'https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{source_repo}/git/commits/{commit_sha}'
response = requests.get(commit_url, headers=headers)
commit_data = response.json()

# Create the same commit in the target repository
commit_url = f'https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{target_repo}/git/commits'
payload = {
    'message': commit_data['message'],
    'tree': commit_data['tree']['sha'],
    'parents': [branch],
}
response = requests.post(commit_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))

if response.status_code == 201:
    print('Commit created successfully in the target repository.')
else:
    print('Failed to create commit in the target repository.')
```

Comment: But you are not cherry-picking (which creates a commit with similar diff to its parent), you are setting the same tree (which is not what cherry-pick does). You are essentially overwriting the tree state of the repo with the state of the other repo. I would also question whether you can set a tree in one repo if that repo has never seen this tree before.

Comment: > I would also question whether you can set a tree in one repo if that repo has never seen this tree before.

The answer is yes. you can do a `cherry-pick` between 2 different repositories